# "npm run build" Command in an Express App Colliding on Imports with Typescript and React Native

Tags: node.js, react-native, express, npm, node-modules

I have an Express app that I build and run using `npm run serve` which I define in my `package.json` scripts serve section as: 'npm run build && node lib/index.js'. Recently, I installed React Native for another project, however, when I return to my express project and attempt to build it with `npm run build`, I recieve multiple duplicate declaration errors in the terminal:

[image]

[image]

React Native is not defined anywhere in my Express project, when I examine my node modules, there is no react-native package even installed. Before installing React Native in another project this command worked fine, the Express project has not been changed since it last compiled succefully.

Comment: Just my 2 cents, is it because there is react-native packages installed on parent/grandparent directory? Look at the image the node_modules is pointing to `../../../../`, far beyond the folder you are working on. Can you check if there is any package.json and node_modules in the parent or grand-grand-grand parent directories

Comment: I can't believe it! You're right! For some reason, I had a node_modules folder there that was causing the problem, I never thought it would be there.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @TheGreatZab for testing it out.

Post the answer here to help anyone who are suffering from this problem.

The reason is an extra `node_modules`/`package.json` exist in grand parent directories which trigger the butterfly effects.

**Solution:**

Remove the node_modules, package.json from parent/grand parent directories